# Vertical bar graph with textual labels

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I'm trying to have a bar graph with textual labels; for example, a graph of average height:

[image]

but on the y axis I'd like to have 5’ 5”, 5’ 0”, etc.; I tried adding a hidden horizontal bar graph, using a secondary textual axis, but I can't align the labels of the secondary axis with the gridlines from the primary axis.

[image]

[image]

Is there a way to have the first graph, but with the second axis? I'm using Excel 2019.

Comment: So, how tall is 5.5 in your first graph? Is it 5' 6" or 5' 5"? I would probably just convert everything to inches and avoid feet altogether.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was missing: [here's](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jyRxQqfPmwg&ab_channel=MyOnlineTrainingHub) how to add the text axis using a hidden horizontal bar graph, as I mentioned in my question; in my initial trials it wasn't aligned because the scale, while seemingly ending at 5.5, in the settings ended at 5.7, which was enough to disalign the labels.